# jquery image gallery with slider stuck with code

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

Trying to make multiple image gallery with slides on one page, but I have stuck with jquery code, gallery isn't working as it need to. Can somebody take look at my code!?

This is example of my HTML code:

```
   <div class="slider" id="1">
       <div class="slider-show" id="slider-show-1">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">                                   
             <img src="some-image-link">
          </div>
          <div>
         <img src="some-image-link">                                     
          </div>
       </div> <!-- end of #slider-show -->

       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-prev" id="slider-prev-1"><</a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-next" id="slider-next-1">></a>
    </div> <!-- end of #slider-1 -->

   <div class="slider" id="2">
       <div class="slider-show" id="slider-show-2">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">                                   
             <img src="some-image-link">
          </div>
          <div>
         <img src="some-image-link">                                     
          </div>
       </div> <!-- end of #slider-show -->

       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-prev" id="slider-prev-2"><</a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-next" id="slider-next-2">></a>
    </div> <!-- end of #slider-2 -->
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   var currentIndex = 0;
   var eventId = 0;
   items = $('#slider-show-1 div');
   itemAmt = items.length;

       $('.slider').mouseover(function() {
    eventId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#slider-prev-'+eventId).show();
    $('#slider-next-'+eventId).show();
   });

   $('.slider').mouseout(function(){
    eventId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#slider-prev-'+eventId).hide();
    $('#slider-next-'+eventId).hide();
   });

       $('.slider-next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentIndex += 1;
    if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }

    var item = $('#slider-show-'+eventID div').eq(currentIndex);
    items.hide();
    item.css('display','inline-block');
   });

   $('.slider-prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentIndex -= 1;
    if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
    }

            var item = $('#slider-show-'+eventID div').eq(currentIndex);
    items.hide();
    item.css('display','inline-block');
   });
```

I'm not so experience with jquery so can somebody correct my jquery code because I know it is wrote wrong, just I cannot figure how to do it right.

Comment: what is the actual issue? One thing that stands out is both `var item = $('#slider-show-'+eventID div')` lines, fix the concatenation so that it's a valid selector: `var item = $('#slider-show-'+ eventID + ' div')`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you @martincarlin87 now it is working fine, it solve my problem regarding displaying images. Did not see that mistake and I'm looking into this code for few hours now :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of problems in your code. 
As martincarlin87 says, you will need to edit the

```
var item = $('#slider-show-'+eventID div')
```

to

```
var item = $('#slider-show-'+ eventID + ' div')
```

The currentIndex, cannot be shared between the two sliders, or you will have problems doing the next/previous slide. One way to fix that is adding a array, and each position belongs to one slider.

You declare eventId, but invoke eventID in some lines. Be careful about case sensitive things.

You have an example here fixed by me:

https://jsfiddle.net/48ta1692/

Check also the HTML. I add some changes to give you a "nice" slider.

Comment: Thank you and very nice solution for currentIndex I was trying to wrote something like this but your solution is way better. Thank you very much, you save me few hours at least.